# What should I use as a key for "row" elements in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I have a gallery that displays a number of books per row. This gallery takes an array of books as a prop and uses "itemsPerRow" prop to chunk the books into a 2 dimensional array and then loops through all the books to display the books in a grid-like structure.

```
export default function Gallery({ items, itemsPerRow, renderLink }) {

    itemsPerRow = itemsPerRow ?? 3
    const rows = chunk(items, itemsPerRow)

    const renderEmptyItems = (itemsToRender) => {
        const items = []
        for(let n = itemsToRender; n > 0; n--) {
            items.push(<GalleryItem key={`empty_${n}`} empty/>)
        }

        return items
    }

    return (
        <div>
        {
            rows.map((row, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="tile is-ancestor">

                    {row.map(item => <GalleryItem key={item.id} renderLink={renderLink} {...item}/>)}

                    {/* Add empty gallery items to make rows even */}
                    {index + 1 === rows.length && renderEmptyItems(itemsPerRow - row.length)}
                </div>
            ))
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, unless I give each div representing a row a key, react complains about the lack of keys. As I understand it, using the index as a key doesn't really help react and should be avoided. So what should I use as a key here `<div key={index} className="tile is-ancestor">` instead of the index?

Comment: You already have a really good answer below, so I'll just add that you can also consider using [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to get the same effect you are looking for without adding the computational overhead of chunking the items into a 2d array manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely need to look more intro grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique identifier (`book.id`, maybe `book.title` if it's unique) for the `key` props. If your data does not have a unique identifier, it's okay to use `index`.

Comment: I see. I almost feared that something might break unless *everything* has unique keys. I'm already using `book.id` as the key for columns, I just didn't really have anything to identify the arbitrary row data structures with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a value that uniquely identify the item, such as the id. You can read more about keys [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Also it is not recommended to use indexes as keys if the order of your data can change, as React relies on the keys to know which components to re-render, the documentation I linked explains that further.

Comment: Hey, just a quick note -- I saw someone downvoted an answer of yours that I commented on. (You've now deleted it.) Just wanted to say it wasn't me. I believe it's more constructive to comment instead, and only downvote an answer if whatever seems to be wrong with it isn't fixed (or I learn that it isn't broken). Happy coding! And thanks for helping people here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found this article https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 linked in the documentation helpful for understanding when keys can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique_identifier which differentiate each of the documents(probably, you should pass the document _id as a key prop in the row components)

```
 <div className="row">
      {notes.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={note._id} className="col-md-6">
            <Component item={item} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
  </div>
```